# When using DataTable and DataGrid in WPF System.Windows.Data Error occurs

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5, c#-3.0, wpftoolkit

I use DataGrid of WPFToolkit to display some data.

The DataTable is initialized in myfile.xaml.cs with

```
myTable = new DataTable();
DataColumn col;
col = new DataColumn();
col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int64");
col.ColumnName = "ID";
col.ReadOnly = true;
col.Unique = false;
myTable.Columns.Add(col);

col = new DataColumn();
col.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
col.ColumnName = "Name";
col.ReadOnly = true;
col.Unique = false;
myTable.Columns.Add(col);
```

and so on.

As suggested here I use

```
myGrid.ItemsSource = myTable.DefaultView;
```

in myfile.xaml.cs.

In myfile.xaml I have only defined

```
<my:DataGrid Name="myGrid" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit"/>
```

When I add an entry to the table with

```
DataRow row = myTable.NewRow();
row["ID"] = 123;
row["Name"] = "MyName";

Action action = () => myTable.Rows.Add(row);
Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
```

the entry **is added correctly** to the grid in the GUI, however I receive the following error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 39 : BindingExpression path error: 'ID' property not found on 'object' ''Object' (HashCode=29890231)'. BindingExpression:Path=ID; DataItem='Object' (HashCode=29890231); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 39 : BindingExpression path error: 'Name' property not found on 'object' ''Object' (HashCode=29890231)'. BindingExpression:Path=Name; DataItem='Object' (HashCode=29890231); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

So how can I fix this error?
Any hints?

Thank you.

Comment: FWIW - I just ran your code "as-is" on 3.5 and it worked without error. Maybe you have a corrupt toolkit dll? or?

Comment: Okay, thanks for that information. So maybe it's just a configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has something to do with the order in which you execute your code. Try changing this:

```
DataRow row = myTable.NewRow();
row["ID"] = 123;
row["Name"] = "MyName";

Action action = () => myTable.Rows.Add(row);
Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
```

into this:

```
DataRow row = myTable.NewRow();
myTable.Rows.Add(row);
row["ID"] = 123;
row["Name"] = "MyName";
```

i.e. : add your row to the dataTable BEFORE you add the items to the row

Comment: Unfortunately changing the order did not help. And I have to keep  Action and Dispatcher, because this code isn't invoked by the main (GUI) thread

Comment: hmmm kein glück...  I'll have a look. I have a question though, why are you using the toolkit's DataGrid  and not the one included in the 4.0 framework ?

Comment: question : how are your DataGridColumns created ? manually or via autogenerateColumns ?

Comment: I have copied your code into a small test project I had to try and get your error, but did not manage to reproduce it. By me, the row is added without the error. Only difference with you : I'm using 4.0 (so not the toolkit dataGrid), but I don't think this is the pb, and also I'm using the same thread to display (so the Dispatcher.Invoke does not make any difference), and this might actually be the pb. 

So I do not really have a solution, but I think you should have a look into your threads to find the culprit

Comment: Microsoft fixed for 4.0 a similar error, maybe that's the reason why this error does not occur with 4.0 (see http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/484240/wpf-drag-drop-database-databinding-datagrid-throws-an-exception-for-every-column#details )

Comment: I don't think Dispatcher.Invoke is the problem as I tried it without and invoked directly from the GUI, which also caused these errors. I'll investigate a little further

Comment: ah yes indeed, it seems you're stuck with those bogus messages from MS if you really have to work with 3.5 and the toolkit... sorry...